# Problem when Managing Emails and Metadata in Mayan EDMS

Tags: jinja2, invoice, mayanedms

We are facing a challenge in trying to manage multiple email addresses and their metadata. Currently, we are extracting data from the emails and adding additional metadata to facilitate their management. However, we are having difficulty achieving the desired result and are hoping someone can provide guidance.

Our goal is to manage multiple emails that may come from multiple people. To achieve this, we are using OCR and tags. We want to apply tags to emails based on their OCR content, and we are using the following condition in our Jinja2 templates:

```
{% if "Microsoft" in workflow_instance.document.ocr_content|join:" " %}True{% endif %}
```

However, it seems that this condition is not working as expected. We want the condition to check if the OCR content of the email document contains the word "Microsoft" and, if so, apply corresponding tags.

Can someone help us manage this problem? It would be a great help

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833). This also holds for things as "Could someone give us a hand". Instead, ask a question *about your problem itself*.